# Selenium explicit wait is not working but "find_elements" is working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am going to test https://www.expedia.com website, they have a flights section, I want to move to this page by CLICKING A LINK using EXPLICIT WAIT not just going to https://www.expedia.com/?pwaLob=wizard-flight-pwa
[image]

So I have tried it using the code below, but that's not working

```py
        flight_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Flights"))).click()
        flight_button.click()
```

But when I try using the code below, that's working:

```py
        flight_button = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Flights')
        flight_button.click()
```

But I want to use an Explicit wait. What do you suggest?

The full code (install selenium and WebDriver_manager latest versions) :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://www.expedia.com/"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install())

    try:
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(url)

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

        # Implicit wait
        # flight_button = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Flights')
        # flight_button.click()

        # Explicit wait
        flight_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Flights")))
        flight_button.click()

        # https://www.expedia.com/?pwaLob=wizard-flight-pwa

    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR", e)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Why clicking twice?   `flight_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Flights"))).click()
        flight_button.click()`

you are clicking on the link in your wait line itself. Then why trying to click again in the second line?

Comment: @AnandGautam sorry, I mistyped when copied to StackOverFlow, that's not working anyways.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? What error / exception appears? For what code line?

Comment: @Prophet nothing happens in browser, no errors, could it be because of the website?

Comment: Please let me know if my guess was correct?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue here caused by using not correctly selected locator.
Instead of

```py
flight_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Flights")))
flight_button.click()
```

Please try this:

```py
flight_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'flight-pwa')]")))
flight_button.click()
```

Comment: @Probhet Thank you, actually both of them are correct, I found what the problem is, because I was making a lot of requests to the Expedia site from the same IP, they treated me like a bot, and they didn't allow to move until verify that I am a human

Comment: Ah, I understand. OK